# How can I use mod_wsgi with anaconda on win10?

Tags: anaconda, mod-wsgi

[I am trying to use mod_wsgi with anaconda, but mod_wsgi.so can't be generated. It is just a pyd file as below. can anybody help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDlGq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to run:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

Copy the output of that and put it in your Apache configuration file. Then configure Apache for your specific WSGI application.